# Escape character being added when using mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

I am using `mysql_real_escape_string` on all of my queries. `addslashes` is not being used, however every time a `'` is used it is escaped on the output - it is like it is being escaped by `mysql_real_escape_string` and then again by a PHP setting of some kind.

Is anyone aware of any setting that would cause this, it is a pain to use `mysql_real_escape_string` and then `stripslashes`?

Comment: Do you have magic quotes enabled? What version of PHP?

Comment: I suggest you should use a better library for mysql connections, like PDO/mysqli, because they support prepared statements, that take away all your pain when dealing with escaping data. See this: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php (especially the examples)

Comment: Did you check status of magic quotes? http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

Comment: Thank you - I love this site, so quick with the answers!

I does indeed look like magic quotes is turned on. Would you recommend using mysql_real_escape_string() and turning off magic quotes, or not use mysql_real_escape_string() and keep it turned on?

Comment: Turn magic quotes off.  They're deprecated and will just cause you problems.

Comment: I always prefer having magic quotes turned off. Also, I highly recommend using PDO/mysqli and learning about prepared statements.

Comment: Thanks to all involved, I have set magic quotes off. I will look into PDO/mysqli as suggested too!

Comment: If you're creating an application that's meant to be distributed, make it so that it checks for magic quotes itself, and if it's enabled it runs `stripslashes()` on GPC variables before escaping them with proper function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all make sure `magic_quotes_gpc=Off` in you php.ini.   This would cause you to addslashes twice which would cause problems for data inserted into the db.

Also you should not be using mysql_real_escape_string or addslashes on output'ed data.  Only on variables being used in query because it prevents SQL Injection.

A better way to stop sql injection is to use parameterized quires with PDO, ADODB or MySQLi.

Comment: I am not using it on output - only input. Magic quotes was on so it was escaping it via mysql_real_escape_string and then again via magic quotes, so the output contains a slash.

Comment: @user887515  cool you should mark this as the correct answer to your problem.